# Report portal installation giving Error response from daemon error

Tags: reportportal

I am trying to install report portal with docker referring to the https://reportportal.io/docs/Deploy-with-Docker following documentation. But I am stuck with the following error.

```
jobs Error
rabbitmq Error
analyzer_train Error
metrics-gatherer Error
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I am attaching the image of this error [image: Report portal installation error]
I did try going to the URL https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ as mentioned in the error. I am getting authentication error as shown in the image. [image: Auth error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Please do not expect a micro-services based application running well when you have several of the services failed.

First of all, check the allocated amount of RAM for the docker machine (process): https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-increase-memory-size-that-is-available-for-a-docker-container/78483